# Regex non-capturing group gets ignored

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a novice at Regex and would like to get some help on Regex non-capturing group.

```
('""dasgsa.txt dssdd "wqhweg.txt').match(/["']([^"']+)(txt)/gi)
```

returns `[""dasgsa.txt", "wqhweg.txt"]` as expected.

```
('""dasgsa.txt dssdd "wqhweg.txt"').match(/(?:["']([^"']+))(txt)/gi)
```

returns `[""dasgsa.txt", "wqhweg.txt"]`

while I expected the result to be `["dasgsa.txt", "wqhweg.txt"]`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that `regex.exec` does [something more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) than just 'matching' if you have the `global` flag? :)

Comment: I know that I can find successive matches with 'exec', but I wish I had my result without string concatenation.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that? Do you just want `""dasgsa.txt dssdd "wqhweg.txt"` to be output as `["dasgsa.txt", "wqhweg.txt"]`? If you then want them to be in a same string, you can just call `.join()` on the array.

Comment: Perhaps it might be better to explain why you need this? So that people reading this might suggest a better way of doing it too. :)

Comment: If I go through the matches I get from exec(), I will be able to get the desired result with match[1] + match[2], but that is not what I want. I want to get my result without additional processing. My goal is just to learn Regex.

Comment: Ah I see! If learning is what you're after then I'd suggest reading up [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on the regex methods. Additionally, is [this something](https://jsbin.com/nopihusopo/1/edit?js,console) you are aiming for?

Comment: Yes, that is it! Thank you. Why don't you post it as an answer so that I can pick!

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate (due to the nature of your question), hence no answers can be posted. When people find this post, they can see the other one as well, and they'll pick it up from there to learn too, hopefully.